# osgi.configuration.area.readOnly=true gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, osgi

If I enter the `osgi.configuration.area.readOnly=true` in the config.ini I get a NoClassDefFoundError from one of our imported libs when I start my Eclipse RCP.

Based on [this question](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=197515&S=6d5a4dbe80f1af00087d8cde6cf6a2d4#page_top) I understand it is due to our nested jars that need the configuration area to unpack in. But isn't there a way to make sure this takes place in our `osgi.instance.area` or some other place?

Yes, I could make sure to un-nest the nested jars, but that feels like a workaround that could fail next time we add a new lib dependency.

The config.ini file:

```
eclipse.application=(myApp)
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
eclipse.product=(myProd)
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/(rcp)
osgi.bundles=(cut list)
osgi.instance.area=@user.home/.myApp
osgi.locking=none
osgi.configuration.area.readOnly=true
```

Comment: Use '-console -noExit' to launch the equinox. Then use 'ss', 'diag' to trace whether your bundle is installed/resolved or not.

Comment: Why do you want your configuration area to be read only? OSGI needs to write data to that location right?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs This was some time ago, but iirc I was experimenting with a shared Eclipseinstallation, were many could use the same installation. To get this to work, the dir where it was installed had to be read-only for non-root users.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but but i came with the same problem.
You can add "osgi.configuration.area.default={location}" in your config.ini file to manage the location you want OSGI to put your nested jars.

See this thread for more info : [Eclipse RCP: How is the default name of the private configuration directory (created in ~/.eclipse when using a shared install) constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570638/eclipse-rcp-how-is-the-default-name-of-the-private-configuration-directory-cre)