# Eclipse RCP: How is the default name of the private configuration directory (created in ~/.eclipse when using a shared install) constructed?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

**Situation**

I have developed an Eclipse RCP application. This application may be installed on both Windows and Linux systems.

If this **application** is installed in Administrator mode (Windows) or by a superuser (Linux), the application is typically installed in a **write-protected shared install directory**.

- On Windows, our product installer is always run in *Administrator*-mode. The default installation directory is the (write-protected) `C:\Program Files\MyProduct`.
- On Linux, the installer can be run by both a normal user and a superuser. For a superuser the default installation directory is the (also write-protected) `/opt/MyProduct`.

This is what Eclipse itself calls a [shared install](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html&cp=2_1_3_7).

Obviously, a normal user running the application does not have rights to modify this directory. Therefore, **runtime data** such as changed configuration data or auto-updated plug-ins are written to a **user-specific private configuration area**.

- On Windows this defaults to a subdirectory of `$USERPROFILE\.eclipse\`.
- On Linux this also defaults to a subdirectory of `~/.eclipse/`

**Problem**

By default the private directory within `.eclipse` has a seemingly random name:

```
.eclipse/1410846118
```

If I add an `.eclipseproduct` metadata file, the default behaviour changes. The content of the file is described in this [forum post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t31936.html):

```
# FILE:
name=MyProduct
id=com.mycompany.myproduct.gui.product
version=1.8.17
```

This results in a private directory with the following name:

```
.eclipse/com.mycompany.myproduct.gui.product_1.8.17_1410846118/
```

This means although the product ID and version are now used, the same seemingly random number is still present as a suffix.

My question is simple: what is this number and how can I calculate it?

Eclipse seems to be able to calculate it after installation. However, I don't seem to find it in any file of the shared installation using

```
sudo find /opt/MyProduct -name '*' | xargs grep -e '1410846118'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for this seems to be in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.LocationManager`. This looks for the product id in a file called `.eclipseproduct` in the installation directory. If the file does not exist it uses the hash code of the install directory path which is presumably what you are seeing.

So I think you need an `.eclipseproduct` file. See [Define .eclipseproduct during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061666/define-eclipseproduct-during-build) for some more information.

Edit:

Even with the product file the hash code is still appended. The hash is calculated using this:

```
File installDir = path of install directory from osgi.install.area
int hashCode;
try {
    hashCode = installDir.getCanonicalPath().hashCode();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // fall back to absolute path
    hashCode = installDir.getAbsolutePath().hashCode();
}
if (hashCode < 0)
    hashCode = -(hashCode);
String installDirHash = String.valueOf(hashCode);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested the `.eclipseproduct` file and this is used indeed, but the hash is still used as suffix. I integrated this into my question!

Comment: Yes looking at code again the hash is always appended. Added description of how it is calculated.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have any idea if I can overrule this directory completely? I tried to set the `osgi.user.area` and `osgi.user.area.default` properties, but user-specific stuff always gets placed in `~/.eclipse`...

Comment: Looks like it might use `osgi.configuration.area.default`